# Difficulty finding oil filter for 2012 Mazda 3

Tags: mazda, oil-change, mazda-3, oil-filter

My GF's Mazda 3 S 2012 came with a filter that was `Hastings LF113`. The almighty interwebs couldn't tell me how that converts to other brands so I went into the book at AutoZone to find it by the make and model. It told me STP3614, which I got but when I got back home it was not the same (should have brought the old in a ziplock bag).

For the lack of something that by now I was hoping to easily find online, can you tell me how to convert that filter to something available at a large brick-n-mortar store, STP, Fram etc.

Last but not least, why aren't oil filters standard sized like oil is? The same filter by two different manufacturers sometimes has the same, sometimes different number, it's very confusing.

Comment: Any brick and mortar store can look it up on their computer.....

Comment: Re your last but not least, Why aren’t cars standard?  Two models 4 seats and a bus, then a pickup...

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Hastings Catalog](http://catalog.hastingsfilter.com/PartSpecification.asp?URL=PartEntry.asp&partnumber=LF113), the LF113 converts to the following filters:

- Ford E9Gz-6731-A
- Kia OB63-11-4302
- Mazda B6Y1-14-302
- Motorcraft FL816
- Baldwin B1400

About the only one I see listed which may be in the stores is the Motorcraft. It translates to the following brands:

- WIX 51365 (probably the easiest to find of these three)
- Bosch 3300
- DENSO 1502002

If all else fails, you can go directly to the Mazda parts department (or even Ford) and get a filter for the Mazda 3S. Hopefully one of these filters will help. If they don't, [here is where](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/mazda,2012,3,2.0l+l4,1502924,engine,oil+filter,5340) I found information on your filter. I don't know the VIN # of the car, but the eighth digit (engine code) makes a difference deciphering which one to get. (NOTE: Double check when you go to that link I select the correct engine for your GF's car. It may make a difference.)

> ... why aren't oil filters standard sized like oil is?

Many of them are pretty much the same, but some searching may be involved. PS: Don't believe everything those manuals or search kiosks tell you at the parts store. I continually find things which aren't right using them. I hate having to take parts back to get the right one.